# How to pass integer arguments to R-script from python

Tags: python, r

i have the below posted R-code and i want to pass the parameter `n`from python code and display the results. that is, if i passed 4 then 16 must be printed out on the screen.
please let me know how to pass argumnets to R-script from python

**R-Code**:

```
Square <- function(n) {
return(n^2)
}
```

**Python-code**:

```
command ='Rscript'
path2Func1Script ='/var/www/aw/Rcodes/func-1.R'
args = [3]
cmd = [command, path2Func1Script]

output = None
try:
    x = subprocess.call(cmd + args, shell=True)
    print("x: ", x)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    output = e.output
    print("output: ", output)
```

Comment: Can you add to the question the python version you are using?

Comment: Hi @Letsamrit, I have conducted further testing and research and have made sure my answer answers everything, and I hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

I see you are doing this manually may I suggest you use an awesome python library built for this called `rpy2`. [Rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/index.html) provides a lot of functionality to use R libraries and functions from python itself without having to manually call the `r` script in a command line argument from `python` using subprocess, and this not only makes it easier to code but is more efficient.

The most important thing to note is that to parse a python integer list to an r function you need to convert it to an r `IntVector` like so `robjects.vectors.IntVector()`.Another thing to mention is you need to set your `R_HOME` environment variable to the path of your R installation if you are using windows

**Firstly install `rpy2` by using conda(`pip` only works on `linux` with this package):**

```
conda install -c conda-forge rpy2
```

**Here is the code python code:**

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects


# Defining the R script and loading the instance in Python
r = robjects.r
r['source']('func-1.R')

# Loading the function we have defined in R.
square_func = robjects.globalenv['Square']

# defining the args
args = robjects.vectors.IntVector([3])

#Invoking the R function and getting the result
result_r = square_func(args)

#printing it.
print('x: ' , result_r)
```

**Output:**

```
x: [1] 9
```

Comment: would you please show me how to adapt the code to pass array of integers ?

Comment: You can also encapsulate the code in the R source file in a namespace. See https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-arbitrary-r-code-as-a-package